# Simple question about probability in lottery numbers

Tags: probability, statistics, gambling

I recently had a debate with a cousin of mine that uses all zeros in their lottery tickets. I think this is somewhere around 6 or 8 zeros. I had it in my head that that would be a poor lottery number as the chance of getting the same numbers following one another decreases exponentially with each successive instance. I do remember from my university statistics class that there is a formula which can explain this one way or the other, but I can't remember what it is. So my question is, would 00000000 be as good a lottery number as, say, 19384928? Further expanding on this idea, how different would 00000000 be from 12345678?

Thanks for reading, apologies if this question has been answered here already.

Edit: Thank you for the replies, everyone! To clarify, the lottery in question uses the ball method, so I don't believe it would have a uniform distribution per instance. I hope that clarifies. I'm also curious if anyone knows the formula for predicting the likelihood of the next number in a sequence? So for example, could it be determined what the mathematical probability of getting 8 zeros in a row would be, provided there isn't some sort of machine randomly selecting the numbers with a uniform distribution for each selection?

Comment: I guess it depends on the number-picking method. In Finland, for example, repeated numbers/digits are not allowed. But yes, usually there is an even distribution for the numbers you pick. A number like 57802934 is just as likely as 75903421.

Comment: Two other bits of information are needed to properly answer. 1) Is each digit selected independently? 2) Given that you win, how it's calculated the prize (is it a fixed sum or the prize money is divided equally between all the correct guesses?)

Comment: Also worth clarifying, if you were to have guessed `12345678` but the result came up as `87654321` then the collection of numbers on your guess and the winning numbers were the same, do you win?  Or was the order that they came out as important?

Comment: The end result is that if an eight-digit sequence of numbers was randomly chosen according to a uniform distribution, then it is just as likely to have been `00000000` as it was to have been `12345678`.  The question is then whether the lottery in question did just randomly choose according to a uniform distribution or not, or if they generated the sequence by selecting balls from a jar without replacement where we have the possibilities do not in fact include numbers like `00000000` where numbers are repeated, etc...

Comment: This all being said, lotteries are sometimes referred to as a "Stupid Tax" as the expected returns (*even taking the winners into account*) of a lottery ticket is less than what you pay for it so you in effect are throwing money away.  It is more common for those less educated to participate in the lottery.  Even if those lotteries are sponsored by the government and pay for schools and roads, etc... the ones who wind up paying for it are the lower class while the rich get richer and the poor get poorer.  I feel the existence of state run lotteries a major embarrassment in our current society.